# LIKE query on DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, datatable

Ive just started learning Linq. Ive just created a sample test like this.

```
            Dim dt As New DataTable

            Dim dc As New DataColumn

            dc.ColumnName = "Test"
            dt.Columns.Add(dc)

            dt.Rows.Add("Test")
            dt.Rows.Add("One test")
            dt.Rows.Add("Second test")

            Dim results = From myRow In dt.AsEnumerable
                          Where myRow("Test") = "Test"
                          Select myRow


            For Each Row In results
                Console.WriteLine(Row.Item(0).ToString())
            Next
```

This returns the first row in the iteration.

But what if i want to use a LIKE operator using %? I cant get it to work.

Ive tried

```
Where myRow("Test") LIKE "Test%"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) i.e.

```
 Dim results = From myRow In dt.AsEnumerable
               Where myRow("Test").StartsWith("Test")
               Select myRow
```

`Contains` will match anywhere in the string where as `StartsWith` will only match if it's at the beginning of the string (same logic as `Test%`).

Answer (score 2):

You migh be looking for contains.

Take a look at this:

```
var query = from mem in context.Member
    where mem.LastName.Contains("xxx")
    orderby mem.LastName, mem.FirstName
    select new
    {
        FirstName = mem.FirstName,
        LastName = mem.LastName,
    };
```

You can also use .StartsWith() or .EndsWith().

Answer (score 1):

You can use the contains method:

```
Dim results = From myRow In dt.AsEnumerable
              Where myRow("Test").Contains("Test")
              Select myRow
```